# Form inputs not responding on iOS after building a angularJs app with cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova

My angularJS app runs perfect from the browser but when compiled with cordova , iOS won't work fine with the form inputs, not being able to enter letters although I show the keyboard and navigate the inputs with the arrows. When I am able to enter a letter, I am not able to continue.
It's quite strange for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not related to Angular (first thought as it was a legacy project), only with these CSS lines ...

```
* {

-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;*/
}
```

Anyway it was strange that the behaviour was inconsistent, letting me sometimes to enter a single letter ...